# How can i auto generate username & password in staff enrollment process while running jmeter3.0?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Can you explain step by step process for generating username & password in staff enrollment process while running jmeter3.0. 
Kindly refer the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function to generate random username and password and store it into JMeter Variables if needed.

For example:

- `${__RandomString(10,abcdefjhikklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,)}` - generates random alphanumeric string of 10 characters
- `${__RandomString(10,abcdefjhikklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,username)}` does the same and stores the result into `${username}` variable

Demo:

[image: RandomString demo]

See [Using JMeter Functions - Part I](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733749-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-I) for a little bit more detailed explanation and instructions on how you can use __RandomString() function to generate random username and passwords